# Gradle content not allowed in trailing section

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Converting a SpringBoot Maven Build to Gradle 6.5, Maven works fine (pre conversion) Gradle BootJar (or even just build) fails with:

[Fatal Error] jboss-parent-12.pom:811:1: Content is not allowed in trailing section.

Why is jboss parent 12 being referenced here?  this is an ancient pom, and using --scan does not reveal jboss at all. (--scan dependency list below)

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.0
com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.3.3
commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14
io.freefair.gradle:lombok-plugin:5.1.0
io.freefair.lombok:io.freefair.lombok.gradle.plugin:5.1.0
io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.9.RELEASE
net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.5.0
net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.5.0
org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.19
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13
org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:2.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:2.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:2.3.1.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.7.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.2.7.RELEASE
org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.14.2
```

Alternatively, is there a way to ignore it?  BootJar does not generate a jar even with

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.1.0'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
jar {
    enabled = true
}
application {
    mainClass = 'my.main.class.MyApplication'
}
```

Comment: Is there any `dependencies` block?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in build tools but you can proceed with the below steps :

1. gradle clean build
2. or Can explicitly exclude the dependency :

   ```
   configurations.all {
       exclude group: "org.jboss", module: "jboss-parent"
   }
   ```

   I hope this will help you.